# mod_rewrite: replace &amp; in queryString recursively

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I work under Apache 2.2.15. I have a URL like this:

```
https://www.test.com/home-page.metasearch.json?SearchType=BrandMetasearch&amp;From=PMO&amp;To=FCO
```

and I need to replace an unspecified number of "&amp;" in the queryString with "&". I tried this RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.*?)\&amp\;([^\s]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1&%2 [L,NE,R]
```

at the end it works, but during the execution raises too many 302 Redirects.

Any idea to solve?